# in-app purchase, confused with guidelines

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am new to IOS, The app i am building requires in-app purchase which uses renewable-subscription model. User would browse through many of the available news letter options inside the app and then subscribe to one or many of them individually. Each of the news letters are individually available for in-app purchases.

My server requires these information to be stored in servers database(due to the logic i use to distribute news letters).

1. User info.
2. His subscriptions.

I am confused with these 2 guidelines for In-App purchases.

1. Auto-renewable subscriptions are delivered to all of a user’s devices in the same way as non-consumable products

My understanding is, the user's devices means, all the devices on which the user has logged on using the same itunes account used to purchase the news letter subscription. Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

1. Server Product Model:

"...Store Kit does not provide a mechanism to identify a particular user. Your design may require you to provide a mechanism to identify a user. If your application requires these (for example, to track which subscriptions are associated with a particular user), you need to design and implement this yourself."

Does this mean, i have to maintain my own user accounts? like allow user to register themself within my app using emailid/username and password?

If i allow user registration,

1. Can  i logically connect this account with the itunes account used to purchase subscription.
2. What happens when the user logs on to my app using the account registered with my server, but logs on to iphone itunes using different itunes account?

I am bit apprehensive as i am new and want to understand my limitations and options before starting.